# javascript react pass value from method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following api code I wrote, when i call method `getData(pdf, data, X)`,

I get a alert message of `returning:8`.

Then in the main method, i get alert of `increaseheight A:`
How do you pass the value from getData to main function?

```
import React from 'react';
import JSPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
import { setMoney } from './NumberFormatter';

export const generatePdf = (obj, save, orientation) => {
    const pdf = new JSPDF({
        orientation: obj.pageformat ? obj.pageformat : 'p',
        format: 'a4',
    });
    let dataArray = obj.dataArray;
    let Y_INCREMENT = 8;  

    dataArray.forEach(data => {
        let X = 20;
        let increaseheight = Y_INCREMENT;
        alert(Y_INCREMENT+" increaseheight1:"+increaseheight);
        increaseheight = getData(pdf, data, X);
        alert("increaseheight A:",increaseheight);
    });
}

const getData = (pdf, data, X) => {
    let returnheight = 8;
    alert("returning:"+returnheight);
    return returnheight;
}
```

Comment: You are doing it right but just have a typo: `alert("increaseheight A:",increaseheight); ->         alert("increaseheight A:" + increaseheight);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your approach is correct. But , before receiving result from getData(), the next line getting executed. That's why u are not getting value. U can use Promise instead - For example you getData() function should be like this -

```
const getData = (pdf, data, X) => {
  let returnheight = 8;
  //alert("returning:"+returnheight);
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    resolve(returnheight)
  });
}
```

-- Then you should call it like this -

```
getData(pdf, data, X).then(result => {
  increaseheight = result
  alert("increaseheight A:",increaseheight);
});
```